# Express.js and CORS

Tags: node.js, express, cors, backend

I built a frontend using `react.js` and a API server using `express.js`. To take care of CORS, I used the `cors` package as the following example:

```
var passport = require("passport");
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use('/route1', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), route1)
app.use('/route2', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), route2)
app.use('/route3', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), route3)

app.use(function(req, res, next) { /* catch 404 and forward to error handler */
  next(createError(404));
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {    
  logger.info('Server started')
})
```

All routes work well, until a request two consecutive requests are made for the same route. For example:

```
POST example.com/route1
GET example.com/route1
```

I'll get the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` in the browser console for the GET request. But if I change the path of the routes to, for example:

```
POST example.com/route1
GET example.com/route1/example
```

it works.

Both servers are running on a apache webserver. My backend server is accessed by https which redirects it to the nodejs server running on http.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

edit: as asked, here's a snippet of `route1`

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const errors = require('./error_handler');

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const result = 
        /* DB Middleware */
        .catch((err) => errors.errorHandler(err,res))

    if(!res.headersSent) /* Making this condition to check if errorHandler() already sent an error response */
        res.send(result);
})

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.query.course === undefined)
        res.send(400);  


    let result =
        /* DB Middleware */
        .catch((err) => errors.errorHandler(err,res))

    
    if(!res.headersSent)
        res.send(result)
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet from route1 file?

Comment: just made an edit with a snippet of it

Comment: Hi @spacecows, confirm that the apache severe is forwarding all the response headers from the node.js app running on http to the client running on the browser

Comment: @oseme_techguy i'm not the administrator but i'll check with him soon. but if that was the reason, wouldn't it fail in every other situation and not only in ths particular one?

Comment: Well from the package description here -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

The default configuration is the equivalent of:
```
{
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
```
This means that the default config does not take care of cases where the OPTION verb or preflight is used/needed.

Comment: I suspect a Preflight request is issued by Apache while it redirects to the node.js app or directly from the browser. I think Apache is forwarding the request to the node.js app using the OPTION verb. It is not all requests that are Preflighted, see here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: In my node,js server for every request i make there's an OPTION before. Now that i've noticed, unless it is for some IO delay, every request that fails, OPTION arrives after, and not before.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem in a project a while ago, i added this to my app, and worked for me. Its because you need to allow every origin to access your project.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

If it not works, try to add crossDomain to your requistion like:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: form,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: I tried that solution yesterday, and  i tried it now just to be sure but now every request gets the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Or crossDomain?

Comment: i'm axios and not ajax, so i've tried to use cross-domain as`axios.defaults.crossDomain = true` but it doesn't also work.

Answer (score 0):

Include below code in app.js :

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

And you can create a common middleware which will be used on any API where you want to support cors.

```
var AllowedOrigins = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com'];
setCorsHeaders: function (req, res, next) {
    let requestDomain = req.headers.Origin;
     AllowedOrigins.forEach(allowedOrigin => {
         if (requestDomain === allowedOrigin) {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', requestDomain);
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
         }
     });
     if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200);
     } else {
        next();
     }
}
```